# not understanding what is internal array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, queue, internal

I'm having trouble understanding what an internal array means. I have an assignment that ask to implement a standard queue class using internal array and set the array to 12. Is internal array another word for dynamic array, static array, ...? What is internal array? Also, what is a fixed size array inside object. This is on c++.

I thought is was asking to use a static array, fixed size array and pass by reference. As they are many ways to write a queue, just not sure which one does internal array falls under

```
cont int capacity = 12;
typeddef int element;
class Queue
{
public:
...
void add(const element &value);
private:
...
element myArray[capacity];
}
```

Now I'm being told by a classmate that it means a fixed size array inside object.

Comment: I think it means you must use an array, instead of other data structures like lists, to implement your queue. It is not a specific concept in programming.

Comment: Could it mean encapsulate the array as a private member of the class perhaps?

Comment: @MikeCheel what do you mean encapsulate the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StandardQueue
{
    private Array _array = new Array();  // This is the encapsulated member

    public void WorkWithArray()
    {
        // Work with the array here
    }
}
```

In this example the member called _array is only accessible from within the class StandardQueue. This means that if you create an instance of StandardQueue you would be able toa ccess function WorkWithArray but not _array. All access to _array must happen from within the class (e.g. inside the functions).

Comment: okay thank you for clearing it up. but im still stuck as to what internal array actually means

Comment: It means accessible only from within the class. Other code using object instances of the class are not able to 'see' _array (using my example). If it was declared as public Array _array = new Array() then it would be visible from calling code. It is kind of like a radio. The knobs let you perform certain functions but the internals are kept hidden and only accessbile via the knobs.